# Data structure to hold list of rectangles?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I was wondering if there is a good data structure to hold a list of axis-aligned non overlapping discrete space rectangles. Thus each rectangle could be stored as the integers x, y, width, and height. It would be easy to just store such a list but I also want to be able to query if a given x,y coordinate is inside any other rectangle.

One easy solution would be to create a hash and fill it with the hashed lower left coordinates of the start of each rectangle. This would not allow me to test a given x,y coordinate because it would hit an empty space in the middle. Another answer is to create a bunch of edges into the hash table that cover the entire rectangle with unit squares. This would create too many needless entries for a rectangle of say 100 by 100.

Comment: I'm not sure how it would work when a new rectangle is inserted that overlaps one of the tree splits. I suppose I could split that rectangle, but then in a degenerative case we get to something as bad as the hash table with the added benefit of a log(n) insertion time. Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

R-Tree is the can be used. **R-trees are tree data structures used for spatial access methods**, i.e., for indexing multi-dimensional information such as geographical coordinates, rectangles or polygons. The information of all rectangles can be stored in tree form so searching will be easy

[Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree), [short ppt](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/454/jpei/slides/R-Tree.pdf) and the [research paper](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/papers/gutman-rtree.pdf) will help you understand the concept.
[image]